Detrended Fluctuation Analysis
In R, I am attempting to implement the DFA time series analysis algorithm described in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detrended_fluctuation_analysis
and
https://www.kubios.com/blog/hrv-analysis-methods/
for an exercise/training coach friend. There are exercise physiology studies that propose using RR interval heart beat time series - ~200 beat windowing - as input to a DFA low-n-series alpha coefficient, as a guide to maintain an optimal amount of cardiac effort by individual, rather than assigning everybody the same either power or heart rate target during parts of a workout (vaguely: >~1.2 not working hard enough <~0.5 working too hard.
To test my R implementation, I build white noise series with R's rnorm function. However, to get ~0.5 alpha for white noise and ~1.5 alpha for a random walk, I have to input -the-cumulative-sum- of each of those to the algorithm.
Also, with respect to actual workout data, I also need to enter the cumulative sum of RR exercise series to get a result that ~matches a Garmin application alpha output for same workout.
For the time being, I'm letting my friend use-and-believe my R routine output, inputing RR series with the extra cumulative sum. But I'm worried I'm missing something fundamental. I assume the conceptual thing I'm missing is associated with my white noise series starting from arbitrary (not necessarily equal/discrete time) sampling... In a way, similar to the way the heart beat RR series sampling -creates- the time scale, controlled by when the athlete's nervous system tells body to throw next beat... But I can't find a discussion of this nuance in any online discussions of DFA, or in reference papers. Everything I read seems to indicate you should input the sampled white noise stream or raw RR stream rather than their cumulative sum (since first step in algorithm is another cumulative sum with the mean subtracted, it seems like the cumulative sums are starting to add up.)
Any insight?
